# Loading Custom Resources for Test Cases - Copying the main way and loading in tres files with code

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

I am at the start of testing my game. I have just loaded in GUT and I am attempting to load some resources so that I can see the players stats and validate that they are initialised.

Basic assert to check that the characters max health, etc., is as it should be. 80 health should be given from the loaded resource and 80 health is the expected...

I will try to keep the code light, and if there is anything missing please tell me :)

---

I have set up the Party Member script in order to keep track of the needed stats. (shortened)

PartyMember.gd

```
extends Node2D

@export var resource : Resource

@onready var health : int

func _ready():
    health = resource.health
```

It is expected that I can load in a custom resource (*.tres) with various different types of characters and enemies. This has, of course, been working manually.

test_Battle_System.gd

```
func test_attackSentAndDamagedEnemy():
    
    var party = load("res://Resources/Party Members/Party Member.tscn")
    var thief = preload("res://Resources/Party Members/ThiefStats.tres")
    
    # Attempt to set Resource
    party.resource_path = thief.resource_path
    #set Stats
    assert_eq(party.resource_path, "res://Resources/Party Members/ThiefStats.tres", "Should be Thief")
    assert_eq(party.resource.health, 80, "Should be 80 for Thief")
```

I believe 2 things are unknown.

How to actually set the resource to the needed scene 'entity' (currently Thief) and how to read in the health variable. (should just be party.resource.health)

Thank you for reading this far. I assume it is an easy problem and just me getting used to Godot 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, with some help of course!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660219/dont-know-how-to-reference-other-scene-into-script

I needed to grab the Scene and the Resource.
I then needed to **instantiate** (changed in Godot 4) the scene and add it into the Scene Tree.

From here I had access to the resource and was able to use it in order to complete the initial prefill of data for the characters.

Code Below - Shortened for clarity:

test_Battle_System.gd

```
    var partyPath = load("res://Resources/Party Members/Party Member.tscn")
    var thief = load("res://Resources/Party Members/ThiefStats.tres")

    var party = partyPath.instantiate()
    var root = get_tree().get_root()
    # add tres here, before it starts the ready function
    # Attempt to set Resource
    party.resource = thief
    root.add_child(party)
    
    assert_eq(party.resource.resource_path, "res://Resources/Party Members/ThiefStats.tres", "Should be Thief")
    assert_eq(party.resource.health, 80, "Should be 80 for Thief")
```